# when get_context_data(...) is called in django?

Tags: ajax, django

I am redericting to url with Class Updateview in Django

```
        $('.edit_btn').on('click',pop_up);
          function pop_up() {

           $.ajax({
             url: url of stock_update_view,
             data: {
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function ( ) {
             alert("success");
             }
           });    
        }
```

and the UpdateView class is :

```
class stock_update_view(UpdateView):
    model = part_stock
    fields = ['part_id','entry_date','supplier','amount','remaining']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list')
    template_name = 'part_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(stock_update_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['update_form'] = context.get('form')
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.GET.get('username', None)
        data = {

        }
       return JsonResponse(data)
```

i am callling the stock_view_updat just to get context['update_form'] will calling it though the ajax will get_context_data(...) be called and will i be able to use 'update_form' in my template??

Comment: yes, you can render form in template {{ update_form }}

Comment: But to render we have to call it but i want to call it through ajax and then only refresh the div with {{update_form }}